css property - initial-value overwrites setting from outside
I'm working on a angular-project.
I have the following component class:
export class ReservationTableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input({ required: true }) table!: Table;
  @Input() set colMinWidth(value: string) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "--grid-column-min-width", value);
  }
  @Input() set colMaxWidth(value: string) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "--grid-column-max-width", value);
  }
  @Input() set rowGap(value: string) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "--grid-row-gap", value);
  }
  @Input() set colGap(value: string) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "--grid-col-gap", value);
  }

  @Input() selectedCells: Cell[] = [];
  @Output() onSingleCellClicked: EventEmitter<Cell> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "--grid-flow", this.table.direction === LineDirection.ROW ? "row" : "column");
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "--grid-columns", this.table.longestCol);
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "--grid-rows", this.table.longestRow);
  }

And the css for the component:
@property --grid-flow {
  syntax: "row | column";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: column;
}

@property --grid-columns {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  inherits: false;
}

@property --grid-rows {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  inherits: false;
}

@property --grid-column-max-width {
  syntax: "<length> | max-content | min-content | fit-content(<length-percentage>)";
  inherits: false;
}

@property --grid-row-gap {
  syntax: "<length>";
  inherits: false;
}

@property --grid-col-gap {
  syntax: "<length>";
  inherits: false;
}

.table-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    var(--grid-columns, 1),
    minmax(min-content, var(--grid-column-max-width, max-content))
  );
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), auto);
  grid-auto-flow: var(--grid-flow, column);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  row-gap: var(--grid-row-gap, 0px);
  column-gap: var(--grid-col-gap, 0px);
  align-items: stretch;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

Now if I set the --grid-flow property inside the component class it is ignored, or overwriten by the inital-value of the property.
If I remove the inital-value: column from the property, everything works fine. If the inital-value ist set, changes on the input doesn't take any effect.
If I don't set a inital-value I got some error:
An @property rule is ignored because it contains an invalid property or is missing a required one:
    initial-value

How to solve this situation, and why does this happen?
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks :-D

As mentioned in MDN, initial-value is required for @property to be valid, unless the value for syntax is *, which is not your case.

The @property rule must include both the syntax and inherits descriptors; if either are missing, the entire @property rule is invalid and ignored. The initial-value descriptor is also required, unless the syntax is the * universal syntax definition (e.g., syntax: "*"). If the initial-value descriptor is required and omitted, the entire @property rule is invalid and ignored.

/*Valid example*/
@property --grid-columns {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 1;
}

Interestinly discussed in Noleli's post, the fallback value 1 of var(--grid-columns, 1) in your code will only be used if --grid-columns is not correctly defined (such as missing initial-value in your case), or when the initial-value is invalid, such as using 'a' when its an integer.

A valid custom-property, whether or not defined by @property, always has a initial value. --> and what value is the "initial value"?

@TemaniAfif I guess I didn't phrase it correctly, should said value instead of initial-value. What I meant is a defined custom property should always have a value at the time you used it, no? When you define a custom property you define a value along with it.

Actually, now thinking, a custom property could be defined with an invalid value, which then it will use the fallback or unset if no fallback. So I guess that whole sentence inaccurate. I've updated the answer, thanks for pointing out!

Love seeing this kind of CSS-based component API!
The main thing is that initial-value is required in most cases for @property. As MDN says,

The initial-value descriptor is also required, unless the syntax is the * universal syntax definition (e.g., syntax: "*").

To get around this issue, I generally use the pattern of having an internal custom prop that gets the value of the public variable when its set, but falls back to a default value.
@property --grid-row-gap {
  syntax: "<length>";
  inherits: false; /* I generally prefer the `true` inheritance behavior, but it's up to you */
  initial-value: 0px; /* doesn't really matter */
}

.table-container {
  /* an internal prop with a default fallback value */
  --_row-gap: var(--grid-row-gap, 0px);

  /* ✂️ */

  row-gap: var(--_row-gap);
}

Now, when --grid-row-gap is set from the outside, it’ll use that value, but if it’s not it’ll be --_row-gap’s fallback value.

Edit: I would downvote my own answer but will leave it for the comments.
Issues:

I had overlooked the fact that a registered custom property’s initial value means that from var()’s perspective it has a value even if not “set” in the usual way.
When not using @property, there’s no need to do the --_internal property thing when a property is only used once in a component; just use a fallback value as OP did.


Actually, thinking about it now, I’ve never combined a registered custom prop with this fallback pattern. I’m not sure whether, for var() fallback purposes, it’ll consider --grid-row-gap to be set when it has an initial value.

The fallback value of var() will never be used. That is not what the fallback of var() is for.

Got it, yeah, I just experimented and found that, too :) So rather than providing the default values with a var() fallback, the default values should be specified as the custom props’ initial values.
I also realized that the Angular encapsulation mode will impact this because @property is not yet (last I checked) allowed in shadow roots.

hmm cool to know. Not familair with Angular but in native CSS, custom property definitions should be cascaded into Shadow DOMs. I'm not sure if we are able to disallow this behavior. Maybe it relates to how Angular loads the CSS stylesheets?

Right. The issue I was referring to is that Angular has a mode that uses proper shadow DOM. If these properties are registered in the component CSS, I don’t know whether Angular is smart enough to move the @property rules into app css from component’s constructed stylesheets.
